# How can i integrate R with Php in netbeans

Tags: php, r

i want to analyze data using r in my website. web site is created using php. but i could not able to integrate php with R . is there any way for that. i tried http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/ example but it didn't work.

```
echo "<form action='poorman.php' method='get'>";
echo "Number values to generate: <input type='text' name='N' />";
echo "<input type='submit' />";
echo "</form>";

if(isset($_GET['N']))
{
  $N = $_GET['N'];

  // execute R script from shell
  // this will save a plot at temp.png to the filesystem
  exec("Rscript my_rscript.R $N");

  // return image tag
  $nocache = rand();
  echo("<img src='temp.png?$nocache' />");
}
?>
and the R script…

# my_rscript.R

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

N <- args[1]
x <- rnorm(N,0,1)

png(filename="temp.png", width=500, height=500)
hist(x, col="lightblue")
dev.off()
```